# Can DocuSign's strikethrough feature be enabled for accounts with real estate plans via the API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

My company is a DocuSign partner, ie: we use the API to supply DocuSign services to our clients (who have their own DocuSign accounts) within our application.

DocuSign has some special real estate specific plans that enable users to use a "Strikethrough" feature in addition to their traditional "Markup" (which is just a white box). As such, when authenticated users with a real estate plan send envelopes through our platform, we expected them to be able to use this feature. However, it seems that strikethrough is still not available to them.

So, we are wondering whether we need to do something to enable this feature via the API, or if it is simply an issue with the client's plan.

https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Strikethrough-for-Real-Estate

This article states that the feature is available for these packages:

- Real Estate Starter
- DocuSign for REALTORS®
- DocuSign for Real Estate
- Real Estate Broker Edition

Beyond the `allowMarkup` param, I could not find anything referencing strikethrough in the documentation. I tried passing "allowStrikethrough" on a meager hope, but it did not seem to be a valid param.

DocuSign support and sales staff were not able to provide any assistance in this matter.

Our signature request looks something like:

```rb
request = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(auth_client, token, header_format: "Bearer %s", accept: :json)
response = request.post(url, body: {
  documents: files,
  recipients: recipients,
  status: "sent",
  emailSubject: "Document for Signing",
  eventNotification: { 
    url: Settings.docusign.webhook_url, 
    loggingEnabled: true,
    ...
  },
  allowMarkup: true
}.to_json, headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json" })
```

I don't think this is actually relevant, but where we pass in `allowMarkup` is where I would expect to set some parameter to allow StrikeThrough as well, if the option is available.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, if an account is enabled for Strikeout, that functionality can be used regardless of if an envelope was generated through the web console or through the API.

I'll reach out through your Support Case for more info.